# How to create a method with array if else and foreach in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am in learning java and I am at very beginner level. 
My Question is : create 3 random number and put it into an array. No index in this array should contain 6 and 4. Then Show the output of the array with foreach loop. I am trying from last night but unable to get the solution. Please help me to overcome this problem. This is my code below :

[image]

Comment: This is nice and everything, but you forgot to ask a question. Code shpuld be posted as text in the question itself, too. Not as a link to an image.

Comment: Post your code, Some of people can't see your image which is attached they have a limited internet access

Comment: The problem in your code is mostly a compilation error: you don't repeat the type when you pass a variable as a method parameter, just drop the `int[]` in the underlined code. You will then have at least one compilation error (in main, because you've not declared the variable). But anyway, recursion isn't the right way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that can get you the output that you are looking for:

```
int[] nums = new int[3];

    for(int x = 0; x < nums.length; x++) {
        int num = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        if(num == 6 | num == 4) {
              x--;
              continue;
        }
         else
        nums[x] = num;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
      }
```

What we can do here is create a new random number each time through the loop. If the number is 6 or 4, we will activate a continue statement in order to start the loop over again, and we will also subtract -1 from x so that the loop doesn't start again. If the random number generated is not 6 or 4, we will store that number in the array with an index that corresponds with the iteration we are on. Each time through the loop we can print the updated array. If you want to create the random numbers first:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
int count = 0;
boolean isRunnin = true;

while(isRunnin) {
    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    if(num == 6 | num == 4) {
        continue;
    }
    else {
        if(count == 0) {
            x = num;
        }
        else if(count == 1) {
            y = num;
        }
        else if(count == 2) {
            z = num;
        }
    }
    count++;
    if(count > 2) {
        isRunnin = false;
    }


}
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(y);
System.out.println(z);
```

That will generate the three random numbers, and then you can place these numbers in the array in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

below should work

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    firstThreeDigits() ;
}

public static void firstThreeDigits() 
{
    Random randomNumber= new Random();
    int[] firstArray= new int[3];
    for (int i = 0,j=0; ;j++) //i for array index and j for running loop until we get 3 numbers which are not 4 or 6
    {  
        int number=randomNumber.nextInt(10);
        if(!(number==4||number==6)) //if random number is NOT 4 or 6
        {
            firstArray[i]=number; // add to array
            i++;
            if(i==3) // print three number from array and break the loop
            {
                for(int num:firstArray)
                {
                    System.out.println(num);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Compilation errors are due to passing of `int[] value` to your `firstThreeDigit()` method. Removal of `int[] value` will although solve compilation problems but in that case your code might run multiple times to solve a single problem again and again.

This is perhaps what you want to achieve. Try refactoring your code in following way.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   firstThreeDigit();
}

public static void firstThreeDigit(){
   Random rand = new Random();
   int[] firstArray = new int[3];
   int count = 0;
   while(count < 3) {
     int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(10);
     if (randomNumber != 4 && randomNumber != 6) {
        firstArray[count] = randomNumber;
        count++;
     }
   }
  for(int i : firstArray){
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Faysal Mehmood Sir.

Comment: @Muhammad If it solved your problem. That's good. Welcome bro!